# To put multiple boolean values in a single key in apex Map

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to put multiple boolean values inside the Map for a single key, I wanted  to show the objects along withe the permissions such as are they accessible, creatable, updateable etc..
But as of now I am only able to show the object with its accessibility with the help of Map. like this:

```
Set<String> standard = new Set<String> { 'Account', 'Contact', 'Product2', 'Order', 'OrderItem','Pricebook2', 'PricebookEntry' };
    
    Map<String, Boolean> mapsObjectList = new Map<String, Boolean>();
for (Schema.SObjectType objTyp : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values()){
            DescribeSObjectResult describe = objTyp.getDescribe();

            if (standard.contains(describe.getName()) || describe.isCustom() && describe.isAccessible()) {
                mapsObjectList.put(describe.getName(), describe.isAccessible());
            }
        }
        return mapsObjectList;
```

//At LWC JS end under the wire function

```
if(data) {
        for(var key in data) {
               this.mapOfValues.push({value:data[key], key:key});
        }
    }else if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

//Setting values in the HTML

```
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h2><strong>Object Name</strong></h2></td>
                        <td><h2><strong>Accessibility</strong></h2></td>
                    </tr>
                        
                    <template for:each={mapOfValues} for:item="keyValue">
                        <tr key={keyValue.key}>
                            <td><p>{keyValue.key}</p></td>
                            <template if:true={keyValue.value}>
                                <lightning-input type="checkbox" checked disabled></lightning-input>
                            </template>
                            <template if:false={keyValue.value}>
                                <lightning-input type="checkbox" disabled></lightning-input>
                            </template>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
                </table>
```

So what if I want to show other columns as well like isCreatable or isUpdateable how would I achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put multiple values into a single value. This is a core tenant of programming in any language. What you need is a collection of values, which can take the form of an Object, Map, or List/Array. For example, you might do this:

```
public class Permissions {
  @AuraEnabled public Boolean isAccessible;
  @AuraEnabled public Boolean isCreateable;
  @AuraEnabled public Boolean isUpdateable;
  @AuraEnabled public Boolean isDeleteable;
  Permissions(Boolean accessible, Boolean createable, Boolean updateable, Boolean deleteable) {
    isAccessible = accessible;
    isCreateable = createable;
    isUpdateable = updateable;
    isDeleteable = deleteable;
  }
}
Map<String, Permissions> mapsObjectList = new Map<String, Permissions>();
for (Schema.SObjectType objTyp : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values()){
  DescribeSObjectResult describe = objTyp.getDescribe();
  if(standard.contains(describe.getName()) || describe.isCustom() && describe.isAccessible()) {
    mapsObjectList.put(
      describe.getName(), 
      new Permissions(
        describe.isAccessible(),
        describe.isCreateable(),
        describe.isUpdateable(),
        describe.isDeleteable()
      )
    );
  }
}
return mapsObjectList;
```

Other design choices are also possible, just remember that you can't put multiple values into a single value.

To demonstrate this clearly, imagine the following code:

```
Integer x = 5;
x = 10;
System.debug(x * 20);
```

You should hopefully realize that the debug statement will write out 200, and not 100 or, [100, 200], or something like that. The same is true always, everywhere. To store multiple values, you need a Set, List, Map, or Object.

Comment: Thanks! it is working..

Comment: But I was trying to say is can we put multiple values in a single key just like and account can have multiple contacts or Opportunities

Comment: @HJohn Only if the value supports multiple values. You can, for example, have `Map<String, List<Object>>` and then put a list of objects in to the key.

Comment: Yup! got it thanks..